# Best practice for safely persisiting new JPA enities with generated Ids

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

When creating new entities from user input I can't be sure that there is no other entity with identical data. The only examples I was able to find used predefined Ids, so one could check if the entity exists by calling `entityManager.find(id)`. If the id is generated, I see several ways to persist safely:

- call `entityManager.persist` and hope for the best - catching the `EntityExistsException` and either swallowing it or displaying an error message
- call `entityManager.merge` and let JPA do the checking...will it always work properly?
- search for the entity by a query - jPQL or criteria and call `entityManager.persist` if not found

My intuition is to go with the third approach, but is there a better way still?

I am working with JPA 2 and would like to avoid vendor-specific solutions (like Hibernate's`SessionManager.saveOrUpdate`)

Comment: By "generated Ids" you mean IDs generated by the user? Why not use synthetic IDs?

Comment: @Tichodroma - no, I mean Ids annotated with `@GeneratedValue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really can't predict whether the newly generated ID will be unique I'd definitely go with the third approach.

Also, I don't think you'll need Criteria for such a simple query, and in most cases the cost of that extra query won't be very costly.

Comment: Thanks, fvu. I can be quite sure that the Ids will be unique once generated. I can't be  sure not to violate uniqueness contraints on the values. So `EntityExists` may not be the the exception thrown.